# Como puedo codificar un valor hash de un certificado a codificación Base64

Tags: android, ssl, base64, sha256, security

Soy nueva en el tema de seguridad y estoy tratando de implementar una fijación SSL en una aplicación Android.
Según un articulo que encontré en internet, mismo que estoy siguiendo, me dice que debo realizar un Hash Pinning.
Pero no se como hacerlo,dentro del mismo menciona que una vez teniendo el sha-256 del certificado, basta con codificarlo con codigo base 64.
Alguien me puede decir como hago eso?
por favor.

Comment: Hola recuerda agregar lo que realizaste o investigaste, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys fui siguiendo esta pagina https://mailapurvpandey.medium.com/ssl-pinning-in-android-90dddfa3e051

Comment: Con abrir una pregunta idéntica a la anterior sólo desvías la atención. Se puede reabrir una pregunta si la editas y añades EN la pregunta lo que has intentado, lo que has visto, los errores que encuentras. El formato de pregunta apoya el que las personas intenten y fallen para resolver entre todos. Y bueno, me alegra que hayas encontrado una respuesta a tu pregunta modificada.

Comment: La respuesta que marcaste como soluciòn solo es un enlace, estas seguro que soluciono el problema?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

has intentado usar esto ?
https://base64.guru/converter
segun entiendo solo tendrias que pegar tu sha-256

Comment: Gracias ahora solo no se como conectarlo con mi apk para que verifique la seguridad

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, nuevamente te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.